# IEEEtrans.bst file changed for bold year, but publisher also appears bold

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I am using BibTeX in Lyx with the `IEETrans.bst` style. This works fine and I have made some changes, like no URLs and that the year appears bold with this added function:

```
%bolden Function
FUNCTION {highlight.bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
     { pop$ "" }
     { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
   if$
}
```

I call the function in the different types like articles

```
FUNCTION {article}
{ std.status.using.comma
  start.entry
  if.url.alt.interword.spacing
  format.authors "author" output.warn
  name.or.dash
  format.article.title "title" output.warn
  format.journal "journal" bibinfo.check "journal" output.warn
  format.volume output
  format.number.if.use.for.article output
  format.pages output
  format.date "year" output.warn
  highlight.bolden %bolden year
  format.note output
%  format.url output
  fin.entry
  if.url.std.interword.spacing
}
```

So this works totally fine and no problem so far. But for the book entries, I need the year in bold, but not the publisher! And I have to mention the publisher, so I have trouble to call the bolden function to make only the year bold. For the book:

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ std.status.using.comma
  start.entry
  if.url.alt.interword.spacing
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.warn }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  name.or.dash
  format.book.title.edition output
  format.series output
  author empty$
    { skip$ }
    { format.editors output }
  if$
  format.address.publisher.date output
  highlight.bolden %bolden year
  format.volume output
  format.number output
  format.note output
%  format.url output
  fin.entry
  if.url.std.interword.spacing
}
```

When I used it like that, the output generated is a bold publisher and a bold year, which makes sense, but I would like to have only the year in bold. Any suggestions here?

The  `format.address.publisher.date output` calls the `format.address.org.or.pub.date`....

```
FUNCTION {format.address.publisher.date}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.address.org.or.pub.date }
```

...so, I also tried to change the function `FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}` with pasting the `highlight.bolden` function into it somewhere... but somewhere is the problem. Wherever I have pasted it, the year disappeared or year and publisher were bold or none... Since I have really only basic knowledge about this, it is hard to find the right spot.

```
FUNCTION {format.address.org.or.pub.date}
{ 't :=
  ""
  year empty$
    { "empty year in " cite$ * warning$ }
    { skip$ }
  if$
  address empty$ t empty$ and
  year empty$ and month empty$ and
    { skip$ }
    { this.to.prev.status
      this.status.std
      cap.status.std
      address "address" bibinfo.check *
      t empty$
        { skip$ }
        { punct.period 'prev.status.punct :=
          space.large 'prev.status.space :=
          address empty$
            { skip$ }
            { ": " * }
          if$
          t *
        }
      if$
      year empty$ month empty$ and
        { skip$ }
        { t empty$ address empty$ and
            { skip$ }
            { ", " * }
          if$
          month empty$
            { year empty$
                { skip$ }
                { year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
            { month "month" bibinfo.check *
              year empty$
                 { skip$ }
                 { " " * year "year" bibinfo.check * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
```

Has anyone an idea where to place the `highlight.bolden` function? Any hint would be very helpful. I still could not figure out where to place it for a working solution... Thanks

Comment: Still having trouble finding a working solution for this :/  If anyone has an idea, I would really appreciate it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to find a solution!

For the `FUNCTION {book}`, I added the year separately: `format.date "year" output.warn` and added my `highlight.bolden` function.

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ std.status.using.comma
  start.entry
  if.url.alt.interword.spacing
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.warn }
    { format.authors output.nonnull }
  if$
  name.or.dash
  format.book.title.edition output
  format.series output
  author empty$
    { skip$ }
    { format.editors output }
  if$
  format.address.publisher.date output
  format.date "year" output.warn   %added this line
  highlight.bolden                 %bolden year
  format.volume output
  format.number output
  format.note output
%  format.url output               %No URL Output
  fin.entry
  if.url.std.interword.spacing
}
```

Not to get a double year entry, I deleted the following part in the `format.address.publisher.date`:

```
FUNCTION {format.address.publisher.date}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn } %format.address.org.or.pub.date -> deleted
```

So this works fine for me :) If anyone run into the same problem: Hope this helps you! Cheers